# Is `autoLoadEntities: true` meaningful in TypeORM + NestJS if we need to enumerate the Entities anyway?

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

If I have understood correctly, when setup the configuration of TypeORM, we need to specify ever `autoLoadEntities: true` with `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ Entitry1, Entity2, ..., EntityN ])` or `entites: [ Entitry1, Entity2, ..., EntityN  ]`.

Anyway, we need to list all entities. If so, what the benefits of `autoLoadEntities: true`?

One reason already has been explained by the documentation:

> In addition, referencing entities from the root module breaks
> application domain boundaries and causes leaking implementation
> details to other parts of the application.
> [NestJS
> documentation](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/database#auto-load-entities)

Any others?

By the way, working with migrations does we need to specify `Entities` anyway? I have watched some lessons (for example, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ty_Zs2w3KYo&t=534s)) and there entities has been explicitly specifies

```js
/* typeorm-cli.config.ts */
export default new DataSource({
  type: 'postgres',
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 5432,
  username: 'postgres',
  password: 'pass123',
  database: 'postgres',
  entities: [
     Entity1, Entity2, ..., EntityN
     // OR
     "dist/**/*.entity.js"
  ],
  migrations: [ Migration1, Migration2, ..., MigrationN ],
});
```

What I am trying to say is I am suspecting that I don't need `autoLoadEntities: true` and `TypeOrmModule.forFeature([ Entitry1, Entity2, ..., EntityN ])` anymore and in this question I am going to check this hypothesis.

Answer (score 3):

If you use `autoLoadEntities` you can actually omit the `entities` property and Nest will automatically add it for you based on the entities passed to `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` calls

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have understand what you said, but what we will win if we need to enumerate the entities anyway (inside `TypeOrmModule.forFeature()` instead of `entities`)?

Comment: Like the docs say, you keep them out of your `AppModule `which makes it less dependent on the rest of your code for starters. It also helps cases with `webpack` where things like `dist/**/entities/*.js` doesn't work. In the end, TypeORM **needs** to know about the entities, the option is just for if you want Nest to automatically tell TypeORM for you